# <defaultDocument> asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc

Hace unos días contrate un hosting con windows server 2016, es un host compartido.

Me cree una cuenta ftp, subí los archivos de un sitio creado en asp.net mvc con filezilla y cuando voy a ver si estaba funcionando desde el dominio me encuentro con que arroja un codigo 403.

> **403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

Como no conseguía encontrar que era lo que estaba causando esto me decido a hablar con el soporte del hosting.

Me dijeron que lo que tengo que hacer es indicar un archivo por default y buscando pude encontrar que aparecen:

```
Default.htm
Default.asp
index.htm
index.html
Index.php
default.aspx
```

Sin embargo asp.net mvc no utiliza ninguno de esos archivos, al menos eso creo.

Comment: El problema son los permisos, nuevamente te sugiero revisar [ask] y aportar la información necesaria a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias Jorgesys

Comment: Al contrario gracias a ti por editar tu pregunta @Acr05 , saludos!

Comment: Además de los permisos, asegúrate que en el servidor se tengan instaladas las dependencias para poder correr tecnologías MVC